# Checking Internet Connection without URL test connection using java

Tags: java, connection, jna

How can I check whether my computer is connected to the Internet. I don't want to use URL check method. Is it possible to call an operating system's function using java? For example, in JNA library, is there any function to perform this ?

Comment: Guess how the OS checks your Internet connection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ping` command like this:

```
class PingHost 
{
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            String ip = "www.google.com";
            String pingResult = "";

            String pingCmd = "ping " + ip;
            try 
            {
                Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                    pingResult += inputLine;
                }
                in.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
    }
```

You should receive a response like:

```
64 bytes from 173.194.37.147: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=299.032 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.37.147: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=508.100 ms
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am going to use this feature in a Thread. Program should check the connection per second. If I use this kind of method, my program will slow down after a while.

Comment: @fivetech You can use `ping -c 1 www.google.com`. It will stop after receiving the response. Btw, there are many useful commands for ping http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping. Ping cmd is the best command to check for connection.

Comment: Thank you so much. My app works fine. I set Thread.sleep(2000) and it doesn't use system resources much more now.

Comment: @fivetech glad to help. Any upvote will appreciated :)

Comment: My reputation is not enough to vote up because I am new on this site

Comment: @fivetech +1... fixed ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if a common hostname (such as google) is [resolvable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAllByName%28java.lang.String%29) through dns to an ip address.

Once that address has been resolved, you can check to see if it is [reachable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29).

Comment: Thanks for reply but isReachable method returns always false. I don't know how to manage this issue. :(

Comment: The method basically does the same thing as ping, which many networks have blocked.